# ngx-boostrap carousel add slides with button

Tags: carousel, ngx-bootstrap

I made a carousel with nxg-bootstrap, but when i try to add some slides dynamically with a button, i get indexerrors on click the arrows.

I have tryed to replace the complete slides array but same problem.

Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-itemperslide-carousel-example-jc4a8r?file=app/basic.html

have anyone a idea how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems **dynamic** ngx-carousel only works with one item per Slide. So if you remove the `itemsPerSlide` property and add the `activeSliveIndex` that would work.

I've forked your Stackblitz and make those changes to show you how it works:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-itemperslide-carousel-example-oxm55r

I hope that helps!

Comment: thx for answer but i need a multiitem carousel in my case. I have now changed to a other carousel. For all those who encounter the same problem, i use now https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-slick-carousel and there it works perfectly :-)